# Add Additional Feature in All UI Components(views) that trigger itself on initialisation of view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to run a functionality every time a view is initialised (like background feature each view has it), the solution I am working on is to create each `view` and `viewGroups`'s child classes and add that feature to all of these classes, but that's not sound a convenient way. I have to use many UI Components in my application for this I have to customise all `UI Components` to add one (same) feature what I am looking for is **IS there a way to add some additional feature to `android.view.View` class (that trigger itself on the initialisation of view) so it can be redirect to all `UI Components`? OR I need to stick with the customisation of each `UI Component`?**